# Excel 2010 Chart (bars) where each bar represent a different cell value with custom X axis value as reference

Tags: excel, charts

I'm looking for a way to show where is a point of return of investment is happening thru out the year. So, I want to have a chart of bars where each bar is the income of a certain month (Jan-Dec) and all previous months (shows total profit up until this month), and all of this is shown in reference to a number that represent the investment amount.

for example:
Jan - $100
Feb- $200
March - $300
..
..
Dec - $1200

**Investment is $600.**

So the chart will show all 12 bars:
- where **Jan-Feb will be below the X axis** (which is $600), each in different height of course.
- **March - will be exactly on the X axis line, because Jan-Feb-March sums up to $600.** - this is where I return my investment.
- **Apr-Dec will be above the line** (which is $600), each in different height of course... where Dec shows $7800 (100+200+300...+1200)

I hope I managed to explain myself.

Basically - an ROI or PB chart :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination column and line chart.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a column that contains cumulative sums of each month, and than created a bar chart of those values. since some of them were below zero and sum were above, that created want I was looking for, except that the x axis was zero and not the investment amount.